# How to group all documents matching for multiple fields mongodb

Tags: mongodb, group-by, aggregate-functions

I'm new to MongoDB!

**I need to extract all documents having the same Address, type, and id only.** There will be only a single address in addresses. Others attributes can have different values. see below Test doc for example:

```
{
   "Id" : "123",
   "type" : "T1",
   "addresses" : [ 
       {
        "address" : {
            "line1" : "line 1 ...",
            "line2" : "line 2...",
            "state" : "state1...",
            "city" : "city1...",
            "zip" : "123456"
        }
       }
  ],
   "email" : "test1@gmail.com",
   "salary" : ""
}
```

For Example I've below documents, first value is type, second is id, third is address, fourth is email and so on:

```
  doc1 - t1  1  address1  email1 ... 
  doc2 - t1  2  address2  email2 ...
  doc3 - t1  1  address1  email3 ...
  doc4 - t1  1  address1  email4 ...
  doc5 - t1  2  address2  email5 ...
  doc6 - t1  1  address1  email6 ...


outcome: [ [doc1, doc3, doc4, doc6], [doc2, doc5] ]
```

Here doc1, doc3, doc4, doc6 having the same id, type, and address. And doc2, doc5 having the same id, type, and address.

Could anyone please suggest how to achieve this in MongoDB?

Comment: it would be good if you post valid json document and expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the Mongo aggregation framework and some R&D, I was able to achieve this using below approach:

```
db.getCollection('test_collection').aggregate([  
{
    $group: {
        _id: { type: "$type", id:"$Id", line1: "$addresses.0.address.line1" ... },
        docGroups: { $addToSet: "$$ROOT" }
    }
}
]);
```